# How to prove that a subspace is weakly$^*$ closed

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-topology

Let $ba:=ba(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ the space of all finitely
additive set functions $\mu: \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ with finite total variation $\|\cdot\|_{var}$ where
$$\|\mu\|_{var}:=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n |\mu(A_i)| : A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathcal{F}\,\,\text{ disjoint sets, } n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.$$
The space $ba$ can be identified with the topological dual of the Banach space $\mathcal{X}$ that is the space of all real, bounded and measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ equipped with the supremum norm $\|X\|:=\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}|X(\omega)|$.

Now, I have to prove that the subspace
$$\mathcal{M}_{1,f}:=\left\{\mu\in ba : \mu(\Omega)=1 \text{ e } \mu(A)\geq0 \text{ for all } A\in\mathcal{F}\right\}\subset ba$$
is weakly$^*$ closed.

I don't really know how to do this. Maybe someone can suggest me some theorems that might come in handy?

Comment: You can start by making $ba$ acts on $L^\infty$ in order to get a concrete vision of what is the weak-* topology on $ba$. Then show by hand that $ba$ is sequentially weakly-* closed.

Comment: Hint: an arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed.  You can reduce the complexity of the problem by expressing your set as an intersection of simpler sets, and then show that they are closed.

Comment: @blamethelag I had already shown that $ba$  is sequentially weakly-$^*$ closed, but then how can I prove that is  weakly-$^*$ closed?